# Find a parametrization of the curve of intersection of the paraboloid and a parabolic cylinder

Tags: calculus

> Find a parametrization of the curve of intersection of the paraboloid $z= 4x^2 + y^2$ and the parabolic cylinder $y=x^2$.

I was a little put off by this since there's a $z$ in one equation but not the other. But I just want to know if my method is correct or completely off the mark.

Let $$x=t$$ Now we get the following from $y=f(t)$ $$y=t^2$$

And finally substituting these values into our equation for $z$ we get

$$z=4t^2 +t^2=5t^2$$

Putting all this together

$$\vec{r}(t)=(x(t), y(t), z(t))=(t, t^2,5t^2)$$

Is this enough to appropriately answer the question?

Comment: Should be $z = 4 t^2 + t^4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

we have:
$$
\begin {cases}
x=t\\
y=x^2=t^2\\
z=4x^2+y^2=4t^2+t^4
\end{cases}
$$